# Scraped HTML has misplaced tags compared to actual HTML using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

I am scraping [this webpage](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-fights-fraud-cracking-plumbers-locksmiths/175362/). This is my code:

```
$parent_tag = "//div[contains(@class, 'post-data')]";

$all_html  = $xpath->query($parent_tag)->item(0)->ownerDocument->saveHTML($xpath->query($parent_tag)->item(0));

echo $all_html;
```

The problem is that the final returned code has script tags in a messed up format. This is the original code of the webpage:

```
<div id="sponsored-category-header" class="page-header sponsored-category-header clear"> <script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var cat_head_params = {"sponsor":"SEO PowerSuite","sponsor_logo":"https:\/\/www.searchenginejournal.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/abm-sej\/includes\/category-images\/SPS_128.png","sponsor_text":"<div class=\"taxonomy-description\">Dominate Google local search results with ease! Get your copy of SEO PowerSuite and keep <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http:\/\/sejr.nl\/PowerSuite-2016-5\" onClick=\"__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Sponsored Category Click Var 1', 'Local Search', 'SEO PowerSuite');\" target=\"_blank\">your local SEO strategy<\/a> up to par.<\/div>","logo_url":"http:\/\/sejr.nl\/PowerSuite-2016-5","ga_labels":["Local Search","SEO PowerSuite"]}            
        $('#sponsored-category-header').append('<div class="sponsored-category-logo"></div>');
                     $('#sponsored-category-header .sponsored-category-logo').append(' <a rel="nofollow" href="'+cat_head_params.logo_url+'" onClick="__gaTracker(\'send\', \'event\', \'Sponsored Category Click Var 1\', \''+cat_head_params.ga_labels[0]+'\', \''+cat_head_params.ga_labels[0]+'\');" target="_blank"><img class="nopin" src="'+cat_head_params.sponsor_logo+'" width="96" height="96" /></a>');
                                   $('#sponsored-category-header').append('<div class="sponsored-category-details"></div>');
         $('#sponsored-category-header .sponsored-category-details').append('<h3 class="page-title sponsored-category-title">'+cat_head_params.sponsor+'</h3>');
         $('#sponsored-category-header .sponsored-category-details').append(cat_head_params.sponsor_text);


    });</script> </div>
```

This is what I get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var cat_head_params = {"sponsor":"SEO PowerSuite","sponsor_logo":"https:\/\/www.searchenginejournal.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/abm-sej\/includes\/category-images\/SPS_128.png","sponsor_text":"<div class=\"taxonomy-description\">Dominate Google local search results with ease! Get your copy of SEO PowerSuite and keep <a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http:\/\/sejr.nl\/PowerSuite-2016-5\" onClick=\"__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Sponsored Category Click Var 1', 'Local Search', 'SEO PowerSuite');\" target=\"_blank\">your local SEO strategy<\/a> up to par.<\/div>","logo_url":"http:\/\/sejr.nl\/PowerSuite-2016-5","ga_labels":["Local Search","SEO PowerSuite"]}            
        $('#sponsored-category-header').append('<div class="sponsored-category-logo"></script>

</div>');
                     $('#sponsored-category-header .sponsored-category-logo').append(' <a rel="nofollow" href="'+cat_head_params.logo_url+'" onclick="__gaTracker(\'send\', \'event\', \'Sponsored Category Click Var 1\', \''+cat_head_params.ga_labels[0]+'\', \''+cat_head_params.ga_labels[0]+'\');" target="_blank"><img class="nopin" src="'+cat_head_params.sponsor_logo+'" width="96" height="96"></a>');
                                   $('#sponsored-category-header').append('<div class="sponsored-category-details"></div>');
         $('#sponsored-category-header .sponsored-category-details').append('<h3 class="page-title sponsored-category-title">'+cat_head_params.sponsor+'</h3>');
         $('#sponsored-category-header .sponsored-category-details').append(cat_head_params.sponsor_text);


    }); </div>
```

What happens is that the ending `script` tags moves from its original location to a new one that is way before the script actually ends. I have no idea why that is happening and it happens only on this website (maybe that's because of the code inside script tag but I am not sure). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Haha, HTML generated by javascript will not be shown to you when you scrape, as you are not a browser and therefore cannot run the javascript as part of the page build

Comment: @RiggsFolly Maybe I didn't explain it correclty but I am not talking about seeing the generated correctl. I am interested in the actual source code that comes up when I press `ctrl+u` in chrome. That HTML should match with the HTML I get by scraping. Am I missing something?